# getting rectangular coordinates of tiles of a 2D map

Tags: java, tiles-game

I have a 2D tile map (made of 25 tiles, each 30*30 pixels) drawn on a `JPanel`. How can I get the rectangular coordinates of each tile?

Comment: I assume a 5x5 grid pattern

Comment: yes, I have drawn that, now I want their rectangles. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "basic" approach might be do something like...

```
int tileWidth = 30;
int tileHeight = 30;
// Coordinates in the physical world, like a mouse point for example...
int x = ...;
int y = ...;

int col = (int)Math.floor(x / (double)tileWidth);
int row = (int)Math.floor(y / (double)tileHeight);
```

This will return the virtual grid x/y position of each tile based on the physical x/y coordinate

You can then use something like...

```
 int tileX = col * tileWidth;
 int tileY = row * tileHeight;
```

The tile rectangle then becomes `tileX` x `tileY` x `tileWidth` x `tileHeight`

Now, while this works.  A better solution would be to use something like `java.awt.Rectangle` and maintain a `List` of them, each would represent a individual tile in the real world.

You could then use `Rectangle#contains` to determine if a given tile contains the coordinates you are looking for.

The other benefit of this, is `Rectangle` is printable using `Graphics2D#draw` and/or `Graphics2D#fill`

Comment: why did you use the word 'title' instead of 'tile'?

Comment: Cause I'm debugging my own problems while solving yours :P